# how to set country code automatically by region wise in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

in this phone number country code how is it possible to set automatically country code by region wise. like if I open the website in USA its shows country code +1 automatically, if I open the website in INDIA its shows country code +91 automatically.Like weather API is there any API that should check automatically country code

```
import React from "react";
import PhoneInput, {isValidPhoneNumber
} from "react-phone-number-input";
export default function App() {
  const [fields, setFields] = React.useState([{ value: null }]);

  function handleChange(i, event) {
    if (event) {
      const values = [...fields];
      values[i].value = event;
      setFields((v) => values); 
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      {fields.map((field, idx) => (
        <PhoneInput
          key={idx}
          id="phoneNumbers1"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter phone number "
          value={field.value || ""}
          defaultCountry="IN"
          international
          name="phoneNumbers"
          autoComplete="off"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(idx, e)}
          
        />
      ))}
      <button
        type="button" >
        Phone Number
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use this lib in your react app so far https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-country-codes-picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect the country, the React app needs to look up the IP address using IP-to-Location services like [IPRegistry](https://ipregistry.co/)

Here is a client-side example with IPRegistry :

```js
const getCountryBtn = document.getElementById("getCountry");
const countryNameElement = document.getElementById("country");
getCountryBtn.onclick = function() {
  fetch('https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (payload) {
        countryNameElement.innerHTML = payload.location.country.name;
    });
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button id="getCountry">Get Country</button>
  <div id="country"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Once the country name is available, its corresponding country code can be set as the default value in the React component.